# Team Foundation Server installation and tutorial

Tags: tfs

A month or two ago I installed TFS on a server.
Everything was working fine, more or less, because I was messing around it, and that's because I didn't know how it works.

Now I would like to make a clean uninstall and reinstall it again.
So is there any way of doing it? Plus, removing all the database files and logs.

Besides that I need a detailed tutorial on how to set it up for the teams...
developers,project managers,team leaders... and how to use it basically with the tfs web site and using the visual studio plugin.

Comment: Have you looked at the installation and administration guide? https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29035

Comment: @WouterdeKort I saw it, but it's not very useful... I was searching something more like tutorial with video or screenshots...
For now most important part is how to use it between teams, developers, team leaders, project managers and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some simple tutorials with images and text for your reference:

**TFS Install**

- [Single Server](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/install-tfs/single-server)
- [Dual Server](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/install-tfs/dual-server)
- [Multiple Server](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/install-tfs/multiple-server)
- [A Video with TFS 2013 Standard Single Server Install & Configure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U69JMzIZXro)

**TFS uninstall and clear Database**

You can uninstall Microsoft Team Foundation Server from your computer by using the Add/Remove Program feature in the Window's Control Panel.

- [Completely Uninstall Visual Studio Team System Team Foundation Server
  from Computer](http://www.uninstallapp.com/article/How-to-uninstall-Visual-Studio-Team-System-Team-Foundation-Server.html)
- [Clean Up database and log files](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19932.reduce-the-size-of-tfs-databases-after-cleaning-some-source-control-files.aspx)

**Using TFS with web portal and  Team Explorer(Visual Studio)**

- [Work in  TFS web portal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee523998.aspx)
- [Work in Team Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh500420.aspx)